# JQuery check the presence of an attribute

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have to add an data attribute like the code below.

```
<div data-mybool="true">
```

With the code above all works fine, although I have to write to much code with thymeleaf.

To optimize my code I want write something like this:

```
<div data-mybool>
```

With the code like above I don't know to check properly the presence of the attribute.

Comment: `if( jQuery('div').data('mybool')) { /* div contains the custom attribute */ } ` ?

Comment: How do you currently check for it?

Comment: Also `$("div[data-mybool]").length > 0`

Comment: @epascarello now I check the first code ```$('div').data('mybool')```